# How do I change the background colour of my visual studio extension on the marketplace?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have created a color theme for the visual studio extension and I wanted the background to be painted Black but instead I got the default background colour of a White-Light Gray mix (in the screenshot). How do I change the colour of the background (circled in red)?

[image: Screenshot of the extension on the marketplace]

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following to `package.json` should do the trick:

```json
"galleryBanner": {
    "theme": "dark",
    "color": "#000000"
}
```

Setting the `"theme"` to `"dark"` makes it use a white font color for the text so that that's still readable.